# C# gRPC inside kubernetes cluster cannot resolve DNS name to other service

Tags: c#, kubernetes, grpc, google-kubernetes-engine

I trying to debug it for few hours to no effect. I either do know how to google it or it unusual issue.

I have Kubernetes Engine cluster on google cloud. To test it I deploy simple app:
https://github.com/iniside/uSpark
It is composed from three console apps:

- GreeterServer - Frontend with gRPC and Google Endpoints
- Greeter.Backend - Backend with gRPC service.
- uSpark - client console app.

All of them are using .NET Core 2.1, gRPC 1.12, and C#. Kubernetes Engine is 1.10

I already tried to see if the service dns is resolved inside cluster.
I also tried to call service directly by it's IP when creating Channel.

Either of those end up with:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Name resolution failure")'
```

GreeterServer is trying to talk to Greeter.Backend:

```
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHelloAgain(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    Channel channel = new Channel("grpc-greeter-backend.default.svc.cluster.local", 9000, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    var backendClient = new GreeterBackend.GreeterBackendClient(channel);

    var reply = backendClient.SayHelloFromBackend(new BackendHelloRequest { Name = "iniside" });
    channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait(); //not neeed to wait, but easier to debug now.
    return Task.FromResult<HelloReply>(new HelloReply { Message = "Hello Again " + request.Name + " " + reply.Message });
}
```

And this is code of my backend:

```
class GreeterBackendImpl : GreeterBackend.GreeterBackendBase
{
    public override Task<BackendHelloReply> SayHelloFromBackend(BackendHelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<BackendHelloReply>(new BackendHelloReply { Message = "Hello " + request.Name + " From Backend"});
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Server server = new Server
        {
            Services = { GreeterBackend.BindService(new GreeterBackendImpl()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort("127.0.0.1", 9000, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };

        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Gretter server is linstening on port 50051");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop server");

        int read = Console.Read();
        while (read < 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Configuration of Frontend:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: esp-grpc-greeter
spec:
  ports:
  # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9100
    protocol: TCP
    name: http2
  selector:
    app: esp-grpc-greeter
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: esp-grpc-greeter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: esp-grpc-greeter
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
        args: [
          "--http2_port=9100",
          "--service=hellohorld3.endpoints.sa-game-206414.cloud.goog",
          "--rollout_strategy=managed",
          "--backend=grpc://127.0.0.1:9000"
        ]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9100
      - name: greeter
        image: eu.gcr.io/sa-game-206414/greeter-service:v1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

Backend Configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-greeter-backend
spec:
  ports:
  # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http2
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http2900
  selector:
    app: grpc-greeter-backend
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grpc-greeter-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grpc-greeter-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: greeter-backend
        image: eu.gcr.io/sa-game-206414/greeter-backend:b1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
```

Comment: Just a hunch. Try just `"grpc-greeter-backend"` as the host argument (rather than the FQDN) in the client, and make the server bind to all addresses with `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`, otherwise it will never pick up any connections from beyond localhost.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those changes helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed issue and it was two fold. First as @spender suggested I did changed gRPC addresses to 0.0.0.0 both backend and frontend.

But the changes were not picked up by cluster. Because all this time it was pulling wrong images.

Every time I made changes, I deleted old images, with old tags (both locally and on GCR). Created new image with the same remote repository and tag and pushed them to GCR.

For some reason the images were not updated.

Comment: Glad you got there. Reusing tags for an image is amost certainly going to get k8s into a muddle.